# Is it Possible to represent $f(x) =\arctan(x)$ as a fourier series ? Why?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, periodic-functions

Is it Possible to represent $f(x) =\arctan(x)$ as a fourier series ? Why ?

Comment: Have you noticed how the words "Fourier series" and "periodic" go together often?